# Pure Css Slider cannot add text to each slide

Tags: html, jquery, css, slider

I have been trying to fix this pure CSS slider and i am not able to attach text to the center of the slider and custom text for each slide..i tried using absolute position but it didn't work.
Please help me fix this.
thanks

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/jibbon/pen/BoisC)

Here is a snippet of Css

```
 .slide {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Comment: In what way are you looking to attach text to each slide element? Are you looking to have a text element at the bottom of each slide as a description or what?

Comment: @dalelandry I am looking for text at centre of the page. And with each slide new text appears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use pourcentage if you want to center a element.

Just add a tag in your li to show different text for each slides.

```js
$.global = new Object();

$.global.item = 1;
$.global.total = 0;

$(document).ready(function() 
    {
    
    var WindowWidth = $(window).width();
    var SlideCount = $('#slides li').length;
    var SlidesWidth = SlideCount * WindowWidth;
    
   $.global.item = 0;
    $.global.total = SlideCount; 
    
    $('.slide').css('width',WindowWidth+'px');
    $('#slides').css('width',SlidesWidth+'px');

   $("#slides li:nth-child(1)").addClass('alive');
    
  $('#left').click(function() { Slide('back'); }); 
  $('#right').click(function() { Slide('forward'); }); 
        
  });

function Slide(direction)
    {
   
    if (direction == 'back') { var $target = $.global.item - 1; }
    if (direction == 'forward') { var $target = $.global.item + 1; }  
    
    if ($target == -1) { DoIt($.global.total-1); } 
    else if ($target == $.global.total) { DoIt(0); }  
    else { DoIt($target); }
    
    
    }

function DoIt(target)
  {
   
    var $windowwidth = $(window).width();
    var $margin = $windowwidth * target; 
    var $actualtarget = target+1;
    
    $("#slides li:nth-child("+$actualtarget+")").addClass('alive');
    
    $('#slides').css('transform','translate3d(-'+$margin+'px,0px,0px)');    
    
    $.global.item = target; 
    
  $('#count').html($.global.item+1);
    
  }
```

```css
body::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }

#slide-window
  {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  }

#slides
  {
  height:100%;  
  position:absolute;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
    
  transition: all 0.66s ease; -webkit-transition: all 0.66s ease; 
  
  }

.slide 
  {
  list-style:none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px; 
  background-size: cover; 
  background-position:50% 50%;
  color:#fff;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
  visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
.slide span { font-weight:bold; font-size:200%; text-shadow: 0 0 10px #666 }
.alive { visibility:visible; }

.nav 
  { 
  position:fixed; 
  z-index:9; 
  top:50%; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  color:#fff; 
  opacity:0.7; 
  transition: all 0.66s ease; -webkit-transition: all 0.66s ease; 
  }

.nav:hover { opacity:1.0; }
#left { left:3%; }
#right { right:3%; }


#credit 
  { 
  position:fixed; 
  top: 40%;
  left: 43%;
  color:#eaeaea; 
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="slide-window">
  
    <ol id="slides" start="1">
    
      <li class="slide color-0 alive" style="background-image:url(http://stuckincustoms.smugmug.com/Portfolio/i-JSxf5Nm/0/X3/Burning-Man-Day-6%20%28202%20of%201606%29-X3.jpg);"><span>Text 1</span></li>
      
      <li class="slide color-1" style="background-image:url(http://stuckincustoms.smugmug.com/Portfolio/i-KMjVHRd/0/X3/Andramada-X3.jpg);"><span>Text 2</span></li>
      
      <li class="slide color-2" style="background-image:url(http://stuckincustoms.smugmug.com/Burning-Man/i-dd9xmfn/0/X3/The%20Steamy%20Car-X3.jpg);"><span>Text 3</span></li>
      
      <li class="slide color-3" style="background-image:url(http://stuckincustoms.smugmug.com/Portfolio/i-KscS8CF/0/X3/Burning-Man-Day-1%20%281006%20of%201210%29-X3.jpg);"><span>Text 4</span></li>
      
      <li class="slide color-4" style="background-image:url(http://stuckincustoms.smugmug.com/Portfolio/i-jQcPqJb/0/X3/Burning-Man-Last-Day-Night%20%28151%20of%201120%29-X3.jpg);"><span>Text 5</span></li>
    
    </ol>
 
    <span class="nav fa fa-chevron-left fa-3x" id="left"></span>
    <span class="nav fa fa-chevron-right fa-3x" id="right"></span>
    
    <div id="credit">Photography by Trey Ratcliff<br>Slide No.<span id="count">1</span><br><span id="zoom">zoom</span></div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please make me a code pen. i am quite a newbie and i can download and study the code. thanks

Comment: Just copy paste to your pen :)